# Statistical mechanics with a freely variable parameter

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

I would prefer to limit this question to the microcanonical ensemble for ease. I'm particularly interested in the limit that there is no intrinsic cost to introducing particles into a system, in the sense the number of particles in the system maximizes the entropy at a fixed energy and volume.

My question is related to the order of derivatives to take when one has found the entropy in the microcanonical ensemble. The following outlines my procedure on finding the entropy and finding the following state equations with derivatives. In general, when we have $S=S(E,V,N)$, we find $\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\big{|}_{V,N} = \frac{1}{T} $. From this we find $E = E(T,V,N)$ - e.g. in a monotonic ideal gas, we have $E=3/2 N k_B T$.

Then we find the pressure and chemical potential via partial derivatives with respect to volume and number of particles. That is, $\mu(E,V, N) = -T\frac{\partial S(E, V, N)}{\partial N}\big{|}_{E, V}$ and $P(E,V, N) = T\frac{\partial S(E, V, N)}{\partial V}\big{|}_{E, N}$. If we want to find $\mu = \mu$(T, V, N) and $P = P(T, V, N)$ - e.g. in the case of deriving the ideal gas law - we substitute E=E(T, V, N) into the above expressions.

But what about when there is no cost to producing particles? I'm thinking of a fixed-volume box of identical non-interacting particles of fixed total energy. Then I imagine that entropy is maximized with respect to the number of particles. That there is a maximum, and not just a monotonic increase, typically comes from the $\frac{1}{N!}$ counting factor that we put into the multiplicity for identical particles.

That is, I anticipate that if we found out a formula for $S=S(E,V,N)$, we would find the actual entropy of the box would be $S_{max} = S(E, V, N_{S_{max}}(E,V))$ where the number of particles $N_{S_{max}}$ that maximizes entropy is a function of the energy and volume of the particles in the box.

In turn, this would yield an $E = E(V,T)$ via $\frac{\partial S(E, V, N_{max}(E,V))}{\partial E}\big{|}_V = \frac{1}{T}$. This would be a fundamentally different energy-temperature relation than solving for $E$ in $E=E(V, T, N_{S_{max}}(E,V))$! The difference arises because on substituting $N_{S_{max}}(E,V)$ into the entropy, we get terms in $\frac{\partial S(E, V, N_{max}(E,V))}{\partial E}\big{|}_V$ arising from derivatives of $N_{S_{max}}(E,V)$ with respect to E.

Which, if either, $E(V,T)$ I have proposed is valid? In general, how does one handle freely tunable parameters - e.g. having zero cost to producing a particle in a photon gas - in the microcanonical ensemble, particularly when one finds state equations via partial derivatives of the entropy? My gut instinct is to maximize the entropy with respect to the freely tunable parameter and then take derivatives of maximized entropy to find state equations, but I want confirmation whether that is in fact the procedure.

Please ask clarifications of my notation. I will try to make my question as clear as possible.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "*I'm thinking of a fixed-volume box of identical non-interacting particles of fixed total energy. Then I imagine that entropy is maximized with respect to the number of particles.*" In the microcanonical ensemble the number of particles is *fixed* and entropy is the log of the number of configurations. How do you "maximize entropy with resspet ot $N$"?

Comment: @Themis I now think of microcanonical just as you say, as an NVE ensemble where the number of particles, volume, and energy is fixed. At the time I wrote the question, I was thinking about a VE ensemble in which the number of particles was not fixed - maybe best described as a $\mu$VE ensemble where $\mu$, the chemical potential, is zero. I hadn't worked with such an ensemble before and wrote the question in terms of the closest one I could think of at the time. Once I get my thoughts in order, I plan to make a second question or comprehensively edit this one to ask about the $\mu$VE ensemble.

Comment: @user195574 Perhaps you can answer your own question then :)

Comment: @Themis The trouble is, I'm still unsure how to calculate the counterparts to the partition function in the $\mu$VE ensemble. I think I'll delete this question and ask that question tomorrow.

Comment: @user195574 I'm interested to red your revised question. I hope you explain what you mean by counterparts to the partition function.